# Evaluate variadic parameters from virtual stack

Tags: c++, c++11, scripting, std-function, template-argument-deduction

I'm making a small stack based bytecode script engine to learn about embedded scripting in C++. The goal is to be able to register any `std::function` to be invoked by script. What I have now is essentially

```
class Bytecode
{
private:
Stack stack;

// Functions to be called from script.
// When a function is called, its arguments are expected to be in the stack.
std::vector<std::function<void(void)> > ops;

public:
// Register C++ function to be called by script
template<typename Func, typename T, typename... Args>
std::size_t function(Func fn, T arg, Args... args)
{
    // Substitute value from the stack to function parameter.
    auto fn2 = [fn,this](Args ...args) { fn(stack.pop().number, args...); };

    return function(fn2, args...);
}

template<typename Func, typename T>
std::size_t function(Func fn, T arg)
{
    std::function<void(void)> fn2 = [fn, this]() { fn(stack.pop().number); };

    return function(fn2);
}

template<typename Func>
std::size_t function(Func fn)
{
    ops.push_back(fn);

    // Return bytecode of the function (the same as ops index).
    return ops.size() - 1;
}
};
```

Then I can do

```
void myfunc(double a, double b)
{
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
Bytecode bytecode;

// The last two arguments are dummy
auto op = bytecode.function(myfunc, 3.4, 3.6);
}
```

So this works, but I would like to avoid giving the dummy arguments. I have tried overloading `std::size_t function(std::function<void(T, Args...>) fn)` but without success, because it seems that specializing `std::function` template arguments does not work the same way as normal template arguments. Any ideas?

**A solution**

I managed eventually to get a working solution of some sort partly by trial and error. Sorry that the question was somewhat vague on the required use cases.

```
template<class T, class... Args>
std::size_t function(std::function<void(T,Args...)> &&fn)
{
    // Substitute value from the stack to function parameter.
    auto fn2 = [fn, this](Args ...args) { fn(stack.pop().as<T>(), std::forward<Args>(args)...); };

    return function(std::forward<std::function<void(Args...)> >(fn2));
}

std::size_t function(std::function<void(void)> &&fn)
{
    ops.push_back(fn);

    // Return bytecode of the function (the same as ops index).
    return ops.size() - 1;
}
```

And a use case with function that has different types of arguments

```
void myfunc(double foo, int bar)
{
    std::cout << foo + bar << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bytecode bytecode;

    auto op = bytecode.function(std::function<void(double,int)>(myfunc));
}
```

So the function pointer must be wrapped in `std::function` but I think that's ok.

Comment: Every time I implement a language I implement variadic argument functions as a special case, where the (C++) implementations takes a vector as argument containing the arguments, and let the function handle the arguments themselves. I've seen language implementations that treat *all* "built-in" function that way.

Answer (score 2):

A function pointer is not a `std::function`.  You cannot (as of C++14) deduce the type of `std::function` template from a function pointer.  C++17 is introducing that kind of feature.

One approach is this:

```
template<typename Func, std::size_t...Is>
std::size_t function(Func fn, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  std::function<void()> fn2 = [fn, this]() {
    // array guarantees left-to-right evaluation:
    double elems[] = { ( void(Is), stack.pop().number)... } // comma operator and init list
    fn( elems[Is]... );
  };
  ops.push_back(fn2);
  return ops.size()-1;
}
template<std::size_t N, typename Func>
std::size_t function(Func fn) {
  return function(fn, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

now you just specify argument count at point of call:

```
auto op = bytecode.function<2>(myfunc);
```

Now, from function pointers you can deduce the types, but in more general cases you cannot.  And being explicit about what types you expect is in my opinion a good idea anyhow.

This solution uses C++14 index sequence and make index sequence.  Short C++11 implementations of each can be found all over stack overflow.

```
namespace notstd {
  template<std::size_T...Is>
  struct index_sequence {};

  template<std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is>
  struct make_index_sequence:
    make_index_sequence<N-1, N-1, Is...>
  {};
  template<std::size_t...Is>
  struct make_index_sequence<0, Is...>:
    index_sequence<Is...>
  {};
}
```

The above is a relatively low quality implementation, but good enough for the above code, in C++11.

Comment: Eh, can you justify your second sentence? Given a function pointer I can extract both the arguments and the return type, which allows me to specify the instantiation of  `std::function` that suits that pointer.

Comment: @daniel Simple: `template<class Sig> void foo( std::function<Sig> );` -- pass a function pointer, watch `Sig` *not get deduced*.  In C++17 you may be able to do `std::function f = function_name;` (language feature is there; uncertain if they wrote guide) where `Sig` *is* deduced from a function pointer type (it may work on arguments directly, or may require an extra step, uncertain).  I am not saying a human cannot deduce it, or cannot manually write code to deduce it, but the language won't deduce it for you.

Comment: 1) I think `fn2` won't be `std::function<void(void)>` in that function 2) `fn2` ends up having the same number of arguments as `fn` in the example use case.

Comment: @blender Fixed.

Comment: I guess what I wanted to achieve by expecing `std::function` parameter is to avoid writing many overloads for all the differend type of "function objects" in C++. Variadic templates are quite new to me. Just for the sake of education: how could `function` be modified so that it would achieve the present goal when the input parameter is specifically a function pointer?

Comment: @Yakk Ah, yes. I completely misunderstood what you wanted to say.

Comment: @blender If you only want to deal with no-overload global functions, add a `R(*)(Args...)` overload then forward to the `std::function` one.

Comment: @Yakk It seems that the proposed solution still leads to error "too many arguments for call" as if the compiler (MSVC15) is unable to determine that Func should have one more argument than Ts.

Comment: @Blender wait, what is `, T arg)` in your code for?

Comment: @Yakk I think the problem in your proposed solution is that `auto op = bytecode.function<double, double>(myfunc);` Makes Ts two arguments which leads to `fn2` also having two arguments in the first invokation even though it should have only one argument. `, T arg` in my code was to extract an parameter from the pack.

Comment: @blender ok, I think I figured out what `,T arg)` was for.  Reworked answer so you pass how many args it takes.

Comment: @Yakk Interesting idea, but is it now assuming that all arguments are of the same type (double)? Due to my original goal, I would of course wish to use functions that have varying types of arguments.

Comment: @blender your code in the OP ignores the type and calls `stack.pop().number` regardless.  I can refer you to dozens of C++ posts on how to write scripting engines that cover among other things that possibility, but I cannot read your mind and solve unasked problems.  I just got rid of your dummy args as asked.

Comment: @Yakk I'm very thankful for your insights. I guess my question was too vaguely set.

Comment: @blender It did ask for something specific.  I think the problem is that the specific thing it asked for wasn't what you wanted?  In any case, I do advise looking at the myriad of people asking *similar* questions on SO.